# Angular2- Is it possible to include an library without a typing file?

Tags: typescript, angular, libraries

I am working on a google-maps app with angular 2 now I made this earlier in vanilla javascript. But there I use libraries as RichMarkers and infoBox, now my question is, is it possible to include these without using a typing file (because there aren't yet) I tried the infoBubble from definetlyTyped, but it is not matching with the angular2-google-maps so it throws me errors.

Does anybody know how to include a library without a typing file is this possible?

This is my component code:

```
import {Component, Directive} from '@angular/core';
import {GoogleMapsAPIWrapper} from 'angular2-google-maps/core';

declare var fontawesome:any;
declare var RichMarker:any;
declare var RichMarkerPosition:any;
declare var google:any;


@Component({
    selector: 'poly-layer',
    template: '<div></div>'
})
export class PolyLayer {
    constructor(private _wrapper: GoogleMapsAPIWrapper) {
        this._wrapper.getMap().then((map) => {          

            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
            var marker_html = '<div id="test"><div class="rich-marker"><span class="number-id">'+ 'number' + '</span></div></div>';

            var marker = new RichMarker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                flat: true,
                anchor: RichMarkerPosition.MIDDLE,
                content: marker_html
            });



            marker.setMap(map);
        });
    }
}
```

Where google is not defined in the index of richmarker: `RichMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();`

How do I define this ?

Here a [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/IVqk3s2SHO5GycpNRnXc?p=preview)

[image: This is the error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `declare foo;` to tell the TS compiler that it safely can assume `foo` exists and it won't produce an error if your code refers to `foo`.

Comment: I declared every error consuming variable, but than again it cannot read properties of the library

Comment: That's very abstract information. Can you show some actual code what you've tried and concrete error messages you get?

Comment: Do you load and initialize that JavaScript somewhere?

Comment: Yes in the index.html

Comment: I guess it needs some initialization. How do you do without Angular?

Comment: According your console log, please confirm that the `google` global variable is available before loading `js-rich-marker`.

Comment: I initialize it in the index. @tan9 how do you mean?

Comment: Could you please help I do not know what you guys mean with that!?

Comment: Can you create a Plunker that allows to debug the issue?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I will try :)

Comment: Did you provide the correct Plunker link? I added a missing provider https://plnkr.co/edit/IVqk3s2SHO5GycpNRnXc?p=preview but I can't reproduce the exception from your question.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer This is an other setup but still google is not defined, or the marker is showing. My macbook had a white screen of death and I do not have the other setup thats why

Comment: Seems you are loading the angular2-google-maps JS code and use it like the plain JS API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple). I think you would need some script tag like `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>` in order to be able to use the API like `new google.maps.LatLng(...`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer hmm, but thats not the way how angular2-google-maps it is doing: `provide(LazyMapsAPILoaderConfig,
          {
            useFactory: () => {
              let config = new LazyMapsAPILoaderConfig();
              config.apiKey = 'AIzaSyCqkkQeSmgHXci2cHDnGU9RTgXP3FONdcE';
              return config;
            }
          })`

Comment: Now I'm really confused about what the question or the problem is.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am trying to use Rich-marker library with angular2-google-maps and my question is: Is it possible to use this without a typing file with angular2-google-maps

Comment: Is it possible to create a false google api link? To use the rich marker livrary?

Comment: Sorry, don't know.

Comment: This answer solves the problem, but see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41101605/23118) as well for some more background and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this with typescript just use any.

```
constructor(restService: RestService, $state: any, FileSaver: any) {
    this.restService = restService;
    this.$state = $state;
    this.FileSaver = FileSaver;
```

For restService I used a type but for $state I wasn't sure what it was and I just used any.
[angular-file-saver](http://alferov.github.io/angular-file-saver/) also didn't have a typing so I also used any.