# google object undefined using angular2-google-maps and google places searchbar

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular, google-places

I am currently working on an angular2 application which uses Google Maps.

I have embedded and instance of Google Maps into the app using the excellent sebm angular2-google-maps module.

The problem I now have is that I would like to use the google place autocomplete search bar.

I have imported the module into my map module like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AgmCoreModule } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';
import { MapComponent } from './map.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: '************************',
      libraries: ['places']
    })
  ],
  declarations: [MapComponent]
})
export class MapModule { }
```

Which works fine re the map itself. However all the documentation I can find ( for example this [thread](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps/issues/431) ) says that the 'google' object should exist globally now and that I should be able to get hold of it by simply declaring it in my component i.e.

```
declare var google: any;
```

When I try this though and then try to use the google object e.g.

```
console.log(google);
```

... it gives me the error that google is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inject the MapsAPILoader into your class, then call the load method.

Until the loader is complete the google object will not be accessible.

Example:

constructor(private _mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader) { }

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this._mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
    // Place your code in here...
  });
}
```

This answer was curtesy of amiller29au via github [here](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps/issues/782#issuecomment-266338100) - replicated for wider access.

Answer (score 2):

Angular runs after the `index.html` has loaded. If you put something in the `ngOnInit` (better would probably be `ngAfterViewInit`) then `document.ready` should already have fired.

The only way this can go wrong is if you have an `async` or `defer` tag on your script tag that gets the google library.

An even better solution would be to install google maps using `node` and set whatever loader you use to get the google library when needed (with the key `googlemaps`). Then you can place an `import "googlemaps"` in your `PlacesComponent` to be sure that the library is loaded

Comment: My question was poor I have re-edited it so it outlines my problem more clearly and +1 this as for mentioning ngAfterViewInit()

Answer (score 0):

You can use the object in the ngAfterViewInit event handler. It is fired after the view is loaded.